# Apache POI Charts - Title formatting

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi

I created a line chart and when I add the title to my chart it overlaps my data.  How do I add the title above my chart?  Also how can I adjust the font/style of the title text?  I want to make the text a little smaller.

```
    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);

    Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    chart.setTitleText("This is my title");

    // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
    ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);

    ChartDataSource<Integer> test = DataSources.fromArray([2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017] as Integer[]);
    ChartDataSource<Integer> test2 = DataSources.fromArray([4805, 7351, 5333, 7183, 6230, 4050, 6963] as Integer[]);

    LineChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();
    data.addSeries(test, test2);
    chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
```

[image]

So from this example what I looking for is extra padding/margin above the 8000 where my title would go.

Comment: What programming language is this code? `DataSources.fromArray([2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017] as Integer[])`??? Should be `DataSources.fromArray(new Integer[]{2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017})` in `Java`. Also `error: cannot find symbol chart.setTitleText("This is my title"); symbol: method setTitleText(String) location: variable chart of type Chart`. The interface `Chart` does not have a method `setTitleText`.

Comment: Sorry yes this is Groovy.  I figured since this was a Java library and Groovy is Java compatible I could use whatever Java answer was given to me.

Comment: Groovy syntax some times is mainly different from Java syntax as you see in syntax for using array literals.

Comment: @AxelRichter yes I agree with your point.  For me though, converting syntax between java and groovy is a non-issue.  I was just looking for the process and how to utilize the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't want the title overlaying the plot area?

The problem is that `apache poi` was tested using `Excel 2007`. But after this version multiple default settings have been changed in later versions.

The setting of overlays for example had defaulted to false (do not overlay) in `Excel 2007` if it was not explicit set. This was a good choice in my opinion. In later versions the default is true (do overlay) if it is not explicit set. That's nonsense in my opinion. But who cares my opinion.

So if we not want the title overlaying the plot area, we have to set this explicitly.

Styling the title font is possible only using the low level underlying objects. Using this we need add run properties to the title's first paragraph and first text run. Then we can set bold, italic and font size (unit 1/100 pt). And then we add type face for latin and complex script characters.

Example code using `Java`. (The code in the question seems to be `Groovy`, but it is not tagged as such and there is no answer to my question about this discrepancy.)

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class LineChartProblem {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {

   Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("linechart");
   Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);

   Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
   ((XSSFChart)chart).setTitleText("This is my title");

   //set "the title overlays the plot area" to false explicitly
   ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getTitle().addNewOverlay().setVal(false);

   //set font style for title - low level
   //add run properties to title's first paragraph and first text run. Set bold.
   ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getTitle().getTx().getRich().getPArray(0).getRArray(0).addNewRPr().setB(true);
   //set italic
   ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getTitle().getTx().getRich().getPArray(0).getRArray(0).getRPr().setI(true);
   //set font size 20pt
   ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getTitle().getTx().getRich().getPArray(0).getRArray(0).getRPr().setSz(2000);
   //add type face for latin and complex script characters
   ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getTitle().getTx().getRich().getPArray(0).getRArray(0).getRPr().addNewLatin().setTypeface("Times New Roman");
   ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getTitle().getTx().getRich().getPArray(0).getRArray(0).getRPr().addNewCs().setTypeface("Times New Roman");

   // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
   ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);

   ChartDataSource<Integer> test = DataSources.fromArray(new Integer[]{2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017});
   ChartDataSource<Integer> test2 = DataSources.fromArray(new Integer[]{4805, 7351, 5333, 7183, 6230, 4050, 6963});

   LineChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();
   data.addSeries(test, test2);
   chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

   // Write the output to a file
   try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-line-chart.xlsx")) {
    wb.write(fileOut);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This works great, any ideas on the second part of my question with adjusting the font styling of the title text?

Comment: @Raymond Holguin: See my supplements.

Comment: Is this answer still the recommended way of formatting a chart title?